# Registration-Spring Boot-MongoDb-Primary key Replacing new data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying Registering a student in Mongodb, throuh spring boot application. In my been class i mentioned emailId is primary key, my intention is here when student trying to registered second time with that same emailId it shouldn't be store but when i am trying to give same email id for registering again, in mongodb instead of error, the data is going to update for that same emailId.

Here is my been class:

```
@Document(collection="StudentData")
public class StudentBean {

    private String studentName;
    @Id
    private String emailId;
    private String contactNumber;
    private String skillSet;
    private String address;
    private String password;
```

Here is my controller class:

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
// This Annotation takes care to map specific response to a method with fixed value attribute
public ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@RequestBody StudentBean userBean) throws UserAlreadyExistException{
    try {
        studentService.addUser(userBean);
    }catch(UserAlreadyExistException ue){
        throw new UserAlreadyExistException("User Already Exists");
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok("User saved successfully");
    // ResponseEntity returns message along with HTTP Status.
}
```

Here is my service class:

```
@Override
public StudentBean addUser(StudentBean userBean) throws UserAlreadyExistException{

        return studentRepository.save(userBean);
    }
```

Actually i am new to mongodb,and i am expecting that primary key will work as like mysql. Please can any one help me what i need to add for achieving  to throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

`studentRepository.save(userBean);` saves the object overwriting any object that might exist with the same id.
You can use the repository insert method.

Comment: i used repository method only i.e studentRepository implementing from Mongorepository. You mean is this is not the way.